# testear un metodo hijo sin llamar al metodo parent

Tags: php, phpunit

Me he encontrado con una situacion un tanto extraña para mi. Explico el escenario:

```
class parent {
    // properties...
    // methods
    public function inicio() {
        // codigo del metodo inicio
    }

    public function proceso() {
        // codigo del metodo proceso
    }
}

class hijo extends parent {
    public $propiedad;
    public $temporal;
    // metodos sobreescritos de parent
    public function inicio() {
        $this->propiedad = 0;
        parent::inicio();
    }

    public function proceso() {
        $this->temporal = 10;
        // codigo de proceso sobreescrito;
        parent::proceso();
    }
}
```

Estoy intentando testear el codigo de la clase hijo. (Como tal el codigo hace lo que necesito).

El problema que tengo es que, si en un test hago:

```
$hijo = new Hijo();
$hijo->inicio();
$this->assert($hijo->propiedad, 0);
```

el codigo del metodo `inicio` de la clase padre tarda mucho. Y realmente no es algo que tenga que testear, lo suyo seria poder testear la parte de asignacion (en este caso).

Para solucionar esto, se me ha ocurrido utilizar un Stub de la clase hijo, intentando sobreescribir el metodo inicio de la clase padre, de la siguiente manera:

```
class hijoStub extends hijo {
    public function parent::inicio() {
    }
}
```

pero como me esperaba, el PHP me lanza un error:
`ParseError: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '('`

Existe alguna manera de poder sobreescribir el metodo padre para que el metodo de la clase hijo, cuando llame al padre, este ultimo no ejecute codigo???

O quizas se puede reorganizar el codigo de otra manera para poder testearlo?

Comment: [Este hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6711647/5587982) te ofrece una discusión interesante sobre el tema (respuestas/comentarios) y ofrece varias soluciones para hacer algo que en teoría no se podría.